# Bash script automating rbenv install

Tags: bash, rbenv

i am attempting to write a bash script that will install rbenv from beginning to end

but there are somethings that are not working mainly i am changing the directory but only in the subshell.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "installing rbenv ruby manager manager"
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source .bash_profile

echo "installing ruby build for rbenv"
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
cd ruby-build
sudo ./install.sh

echo "rbenv and ruby-build have been installed, installing ruby now.."
sleep 2

read -p "would you like chronospere to install ruby 1.9.3 [y/n]" RESP
if [ "$RESP" = "y" ]; then
  rbenv install 1.9.3-p327
  rbenv rehash
  rbenv global 1.9.3-p327
  ruby -v
else
  echo "alrigt skipping.. vagrant has rbenv installed you can install ruby it at your leisure "
  echo "hold cmd, and double clck https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv for more info"
fi

cd ~
```

so it seems as if installing it works. but most of my code dosent get run, or doesnt get run in the place id like it to.

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ rbenv
The program 'rbenv' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rbenv
```

as you can see its as if nothing was installed only what happened was that the `source .bash_profile` never happened

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ cd      
vagrant@precise64:~$ cd ~ 
vagrant@precise64:~$ source .bash_profile
```

after i manually source the bash_profile

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ rbenv
rbenv 0.4.0-45-g060f141
vagrant@precise64:~$ rbenv versions
  * system (set by /home/vagrant/.rbenv/version)
  1.9.3-p327
vagrant@precise64:~$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p327
vagrant@precise64:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
```

so as you can see its as if the code is running just not moving from one directory to the next. i dont even know if this is possible. i move from ~ / (HOME) to /ruby-build back to ~ then to /vagrant. is this possible in a single bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too ran into this issue. The key for me was to add `export RBENV_ROOT="/home/vagrant/.rbenv"` right before the curl call to grab rbenv. Something like this should work (tested with Ubuntu Precise 32 bit):

```
export RBENV_ROOT="/home/vagrant/.rbenv"

curl https://raw.github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
```